# Javascript and associative arrays

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I am new to JS so I am trying to use the associative arrays  and am  getting an error when I run the following JS code.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'x')

Any assist would be great.

```js
var activeField;

fields = []; //  holds all the defined fields

function Field() {
  this.polypoints = [{}];
}

var field = new Field();
var Points;

fields.push(field);

activeField = (fields.length) - 1;
Points = fields[activeField].polypoints.length;
Points = Points + 1;
fields[activeField].polypoints[Points].x = 1;
fields[activeField].polypoints[Points].y = 1;

console.log("values in array:", activeField, polyPoints, fields);
```

Comment: Assiocative arrays exist in PHP only. Their equivalent in JavaScript are objects.

Comment: should declare fields var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make `Points=Points+1;`, `Points` is now 1. `fields[activeField].polypoints[Points]` is undefined b/c you haven't created an object. The object is at `fields[activeField].polypoints[0]` instead. To add object, you have to create.

```
fields[activeField].polypoints[Points]={x:1,y:1}
```

Comment: The (imho) better option would be to skip `Points` completely (because it isn't used for anything else) and just `.push()` new objects.

Comment: good too yea @Andreas

Comment: When I use:   fields[activeField].polypoints.push({x:2, y:2});   The  elements 2 and 2 are stored  in the array beginning at 1, it should be at 0 -  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems like the array already had one element @JackStein